# How to correctly wait the HTML checkbox element to load before programatically checking it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to dynamically activate some checkboxes when the user enters the page. For this I am saving the IDs of the HTML checkbox elements in a service. When the user enters the page, this service is accessed and returns an array with these IDs. The active elements are checked in each loop.

```js
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    let checboxState = this.service.checboxState;
    if (checboxState !== undefined && checboxState.length > 0) {
        checboxState.forEach(checbox => {
            let element = document.getElementById(checbox.id) as HTMLInputElement;
            element.checked = true;
        });
    }
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null

Which can be a indicator that Javascript function is firing before DOM is loaded. If that is the case, why `platform.ready()` isn't  working? I tried also with:
- `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {}`
- `window.onload = () => {}`

but no success.

---

I managed to make the function work by adding a `setTimeout()` before the function, so how do I correctly wait the HTML elements to load before firing the JS function?

---

The checkboxes in the page are loaded by a [*ngFor](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#add-logic-to-loop-through-data) function.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML elements are on the page when the page is loaded, not added dynamically later on by JavaScript? If it is added dynamically, there's nothing you can really do unless the code that injects the checkboxes gives you a callback opportunity. If you do a "view source" on the page (not just inspecting the elements, but seeing what the server response returns) that should tell you if it's static or dynamic HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be notified when the checkboxes have been added to the DOM by the `*ngFor` loop:

1. Assign a template reference variable to the checkbox elements (e.g. `#chk`)
2. Associate the checkbox elements to a `QueryList` with the help of `ViewChildren`
3. Subscribe to the `QueryList.changes` observable in `ngAfterViewInit` and process the list of checkboxes in the callback. You can also check directly in `ngAfterViewInit` to account for cases where the checkbox elements are already rendered

```html
<input type="checkbox" #chk *ngFor="let id of idList" [id]="id">
```

```js
@ViewChildren("chk") private checkboxList: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>>;

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // Check if the checkbox is already in the DOM
  this.findCheckBoxWithId("chk36");            

  // Find the checkbox if rendered after a delay
  this.checkboxList.changes.subscribe(() => {
    this.findCheckBoxWithId("chk36");          
  });
}

findCheckBoxWithId(id) {
  const checkbox = this.checkboxList.find(x => x.nativeElement.id === id);
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk1krk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo

Answer (score 1):

Or, building on [ConnorsFan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374371/23118), by using an observable:

```js
@ViewChildren('chk') private checkboxQueryList: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>>;
checkbox$: Observable<HTMLInputElement>;

...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.checkbox$ = this.observableFromQueryListFind(
    this.checkboxQueryList,
    x => x.nativeElement.id === 'chk36',
  );
}

...

observableFromQueryListFind<T>(
  queryList: QueryList<T>,
  fn: (item: T, index: number, array: T[]) => boolean,
): Observable<T> {
  const item = queryList.find(fn);
  if (item) {
    return concat(
      of(item),
      queryList.changes
        .pipe(
          map((queryList: QueryList<T>) => queryList.find(fn)),
        ),
    );
  } else {
    return queryList.changes
      .pipe(
        map((queryList: QueryList<T>) => queryList.find(fn)),
      );
  }
}
```

This answer code is untested but based on 80-90% similar code from a working code base.